# Closing the handle for a serial port device takes too long, how to make it faster?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I've created a button that sends bytes to turn on LEDs for multiple similar devices. What I have found out is that if I don't close the handle I get instantaneous speed which is exactly what I need, but of course, if I don't close it I can't use it anymore meaning the button only works once. If I do close the handle it works, but much slower to the point where I can see the LEDs turn on one by one. How to go about this?

Here's the code for the sendBytes function, the code for the GUI is unnecessary because I get the same speed with a barebones C console program.

```
int sendBytes(char* command, char* COM) {
HANDLE hSerial2;
BOOL Write_Status;
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };                    // Initializing DCB structure
hSerial2 = CreateFileA(COM,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
    NULL, // no security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
    0,    // not overlapped I/O
    NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
);

printf("opening serial port successful");

dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

Write_Status = GetCommState(hSerial2, &dcbSerialParams);     //retreives  the current settings

if (Write_Status == FALSE) {
    printf("\n   Error! in GetCommState()");
    CloseHandle(hSerial2);
    return 1;
}

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;

dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

Write_Status = SetCommState(hSerial2, &dcbSerialParams);  //Configuring the port according to settings in DCB

if (Write_Status == FALSE)
{
    printf("\n   Error! in Setting DCB Structure");
    CloseHandle(hSerial2);
    return 1;
}

// Set COM port timeout settings
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
if (SetCommTimeouts(hSerial2, &timeouts) == 0)
{
    //  printf("Error setting timeouts\n");
    CloseHandle(hSerial2);
    return 1;
}
///*----------------------------- Writing a Character to Serial Port----------------------------------------*/
int length = strlen(command);
char send[20];
strcpy(send, command);
send[length + 1] = 13;
send[length + 2] = 10;
DWORD  dNoOFBytestoWrite;              // No of bytes to write into the port
DWORD  dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;          // No of bytes written to the port

dNoOFBytestoWrite = length + 2; // Calculating the no of bytes to write into the port


if (!WriteFile(hSerial2, send, dNoOFBytestoWrite,
    &dNoOfBytesWritten, NULL))
{
    printf("Error writing text to %s\n", COM);
}
else
{
    printf("\n %d bytes written to %s\n", dNoOfBytesWritten, COM);
}


CloseHandle(hSerial2);//Closing the Serial Port
printf("\n ==========================================\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: is that windows, arduino or else?

Comment: i'm using Windows

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution, it's fairly simple.

All I did was create a HANDLE variable for each device, initialized them with the corresponding COM port and passed that HANDLE to a slightly modified sendBytes function so it doesn't have to close and create a new one each time it's called when you press the button.

The problem now is that reading bytes is slow, here's the code:

```
int sendBytes(char* command, char* COM, HANDLE hSerial, int read) {

BOOL Write_Status;
DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };                    // Initializing DCB structure


dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

Write_Status = GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);     //retreives  the current settings

if (Write_Status == FALSE) {
    printf("\n   Error! in GetCommState()");
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
}


dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_57600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;

dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

Write_Status = SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);  //Configuring the port according to settings in DCB

if (Write_Status == FALSE)
{
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
}

///*----------------------------- Writing a Character to Serial Port----------------------------------------*/
int length = strlen(command);
char send[20];
strcpy(send, command);
send[length + 1] = 13;
send[length + 2] = 10;
DWORD  dNoOFBytestoWrite;              // No of bytes to write into the port
DWORD  dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;          // No of bytes written to the port
dNoOFBytestoWrite = length + 2; // Calculating the no of bytes to write into the port

if (!WriteFile(hSerial, send, dNoOFBytestoWrite, &dNoOfBytesWritten, NULL))
    printf("Error writing text to %s\n", COM);

if (read) {
    int maxChars = 256;
    BOOL  Read_Status;                      // Status of the various operations 
    DWORD dwEventMask;                      // Event mask to trigger
    char  SerialBuffer[256];               // Buffer Containing Rxed Data
    DWORD NoBytesRead;                     // Bytes read by ReadFile()
    ///*------------------------------------ Setting Receive Mask ----------------------------------------------*/

    Read_Status = SetCommMask(hSerial, EV_RXCHAR); //Configure Windows to Monitor the serial device for Character Reception

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
        printf("\n\n    Error! in Setting CommMask");
    else
        printf("\n\n    Setting CommMask successfull");


    ///*------------------------------------ Setting WaitComm() Event   ----------------------------------------*/

    printf("\n\n    Waiting for Data Reception");

    Read_Status = WaitCommEvent(hSerial, &dwEventMask, NULL); //Wait for the character to be received

    // /*-------------------------- Program will Wait here till a Character is received ------------------------*/

    if (Read_Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf("\n    Error! in Setting WaitCommEvent()");
    }
    else //If  WaitCommEvent()==True Read the RXed data using ReadFile();
    {
        printf("\n\n    Characters Received \t");


        if (!ReadFile(hSerial, SerialBuffer, maxChars, &NoBytesRead, NULL))
        {
            printf("wrong character");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("noBytes: %d\n", NoBytesRead);

        /*------------Printing the RXed String to Console----------------------*/

        int j = 0;
        char readArray[256];
        while (SerialBuffer[j] != '\r') {
            printf("%c", SerialBuffer[j]);
            readArray[j] = SerialBuffer[j];
            j++;
        }

        readArray[j++] = '\0';



    }
}

}
```